# Don't clear current filter while changing the tab in tags and users pages

Tags: feature-request, filtering, users-page, tags-page

On the [Tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) there is filter box and three buttons (tabs?) to sort the result. When I'm changing the tab the text in the filter box is clearing:

> [image: Filter droping]

It would be less annoying if the filter field stays as before changing the tab.

It seems that same behavior observed on [Users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) as well.